# jquery beginner animate img from 1 place to the other (straight line or curve)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I really would like to learn how to animate better with jquery. Not just standard fade etc...

So I've div#1 and I can get its coordinates relative to the document via jquery .offset function. I also have destination div which also has coordinates.

Now how do I move my image along this path?

I googled around, but I only see ready plugins to do this. I'd like to do it myself...

Comment: *"So I've div#1..."* If you literally mean a `div` with the `id` `"1"`, note that `div#1` is an invalid CSS selector. If you want to use an `id` value with CSS, it must [follow the CSS rules for `id` values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), which are more restrictive than HTML's rules for them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm aware of that. It is a simple notation I like to use when I write about this things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the `target` css. jQuery takes care of the current css.

eg.

```
$('#div1').animate({top: '200px', left: '300px'},3000);
```

will animate element with id `div1` to `top = 200px` and `left = 300px` in 3 seconds, no matter it is placed at what position.

(If the element is already at that position, you wont see an animation at all)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div1').animate({
    left: 200, // absolute destination position
    top: '+=50' // relative to starting position
}, 5000);
```

jQuery will calculate the intermediate steps in-between from it's current position. You do not need to worry about the animation.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

get the target divs offset().left, and set div#1's 'left' to that inside the .animate call.